How to sort a pandas dataframe by a binned column
I have created the following pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd
ds = {'col1' : ['(-9999999, 550.0]','(13700.0, 23700.0]','(23700.0, 414580.0]','(4000.0, 8000.0]','(414580.0, 9999999]','(550.0, 4000.0]','(8000.0, 13700.0]'],                                                                                                                             
      'col2' : [905317.3,   606156.5,   586349.6,   665779.1,   0,  803824.4,   628475.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

The dataframe looks like this:
print(df)
                  col1      col2
0    (-9999999, 550.0]  905317.3
1   (13700.0, 23700.0]  606156.5
2  (23700.0, 414580.0]  586349.6
3     (4000.0, 8000.0]  665779.1
4  (414580.0, 9999999]       0.0
5      (550.0, 4000.0]  803824.4
6    (8000.0, 13700.0]  628475.2

I need to sort the dataframe by column col1 in ascending order. The resulting dataframe would look like this:
                  col1      col2
0    (-9999999, 550.0]  905317.3
1      (550.0, 4000.0]  803824.4
2     (4000.0, 8000.0]  665779.1
3    (8000.0, 13700.0]  628475.2
4   (13700.0, 23700.0]  606156.5
5  (23700.0, 414580.0]  586349.6
6  (414580.0, 9999999]       0.0

Can someone help me please?

In the previous (now deleted) version of this question, you added the (non-reproducible) source of your bins. I suggest (as I did there ;) ) that you update this question with a [mre]. The point is that your original column bins was ultimately the result of some pd.cut operation. At that stage, the column will have been categorical. So, what you would really want to do, is make sure that your col1 remains categorical. In that case, you can simply do: df.sort_values('bins', ascending=False). (Your expected output is descending incidentally.)

"remains categorical", or at any rate, is made categorical again by using the categories from the original column.

Why is your column as string? This shouldn't be the case, avoid the transformation to string and sorting will be much more efficient.

Code
out = df.sort_values(
    'col1', key=lambda x: x.str.extract(r'\(([^,]+),')[0].astype('float')
)

out:
                  col1      col2
0    (-9999999, 550.0]  905317.3
5      (550.0, 4000.0]  803824.4
3     (4000.0, 8000.0]  665779.1
6    (8000.0, 13700.0]  628475.2
1   (13700.0, 23700.0]  606156.5
2  (23700.0, 414580.0]  586349.6
4  (414580.0, 9999999]       0.0


If 'col1' has string values, you can use regex to extract the lower bounds and use that to sort. You can do that using a custom key with sort_values:
df = df.sort_values(
    "col1", key=lambda x: x.str.extract(r"\((-?\d*\.?\d*),")[0].astype(float)
)

                  col1      col2
0    (-9999999, 550.0]  905317.3
5      (550.0, 4000.0]  803824.4
3     (4000.0, 8000.0]  665779.1
6    (8000.0, 13700.0]  628475.2
1   (13700.0, 23700.0]  606156.5
2  (23700.0, 414580.0]  586349.6
4  (414580.0, 9999999]       0.0

